# Desktop shorcuts open the same program?

Tags: shortcuts, icons, desktop

I have a windows 7 computer and all of the desktop shortcuts look normal except for the fact they have a even smaller icon within them (see picture below):
  [image: Screengrab]

At first it didn't effect anything, now when I click on any of the shortcuts, it opens the program that is in the smaller icon.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Has the default programs been altered in any way, its like the associated file type has been told to open in the Epic Games launcher.

press start > type " Default programs"

or

press start > type "file association" this will display " Make a file type always display in a program"

from here you can alter the default programs and even specific file types.

If possible remove the epic games launcher and see if this resolves the issue. Did this happen around the time of an update to the epic games launcher

Comment: Ok I'll try your suggestion soon. At first the problem was occuring with Adobe  animate, I deleted it and then it occurred with epic games, so I deleted that and now the problem is with Microsoft Paint.

Answer (score 0):

in my case regedit and all other *.exe files didnt run

so regedit.exe didnt run

so only way that solve my problem in windows 7 is:

> create new user (as administrator)  and move all documents there.